# scroll bar not working after deploying node js applcation on google app engin

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine

I am currently working on google app engine. i was already working on heroku where i have deployed my node js app. I have successfully deployed my node js app on GAE. but after deployment, a weird problem occur. in which my pages does not scroll and stuck on one page. it works fine locally as well as on heroku. here is my **package.json file**

```
 "name": "temporary",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "gcloud app deploy",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "ng test",
    "postinstall": "ng build ",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.10.0",
    "npm": "5.1.0"
  },
     "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.15.3",
}
  "devDependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/nodejs-repo-tools": "1.4.16",
}
```

and my **app.yaml file** is

```
# [START app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
# [END app_yaml]
```

and my **server.js** is

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// Run the app by serving the static files
// in the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
// Start the app by listening on the default
// Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

const forceSSL = function() {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https') {
      return res.redirect(
       ['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join('')
      );
    }
    next();
  }
}
// Instruct the app
// to use the forceSSL
// middleware
app.use(forceSSL());

const path = require('path');
// ...
// For all GET requests, send back index.html
// so that PathLocationStrategy can be used
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});
```

here is the link of GAE. you can check it live.

[https://shopnroar-frontend.appspot.com/][1]

can anybody tell me what is problem with my code.

i have wasted a lot of my time on this problem.
I will be thankful for this favor.

Comment: The scrolling issue in the browser has nothing to do with server code. I'm more curious to see HTML and (front-end) JS.

Comment: its working good on Heroku and on my local machine

Comment: which part of front-end code should i share?

Comment: The part that doesn't work :) nothing you provided so far is relevant.

Comment: have you checked the URL that is provided? it is impossible for me to upload whole project here.

Comment: I did yesterday, and there was a scrolling problem. Now the page has changed and the scroling problem is gone.

Comment: yes i have made it. thanks. my java script between two themes was conflicting.